# Como definir um option padrão num select com data-live-search HTML?

Tags: html5

Eu preciso trazer no select um option padrão toda vez que a página for carregada. Porém com o plugin data-live-search. Existe esta possibilidade?

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
  </select>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu peguei este exemplo na rede. 
Eu queria que quando fosse visualizar a página, que por padrão o select me trouxesse um valor específico. Ex: ao invés de trazer "Tom Foolery" conforme a imagem, trouxesse "Maickon" por exemplo. Setando a propriedade value não está funcionando.

Comment: Ola, adicione o codigo que voce ja possui, assim fica mais facil visualizar o seu problema e propor uma solucao :)

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer:

```
<option selected>Minha Opção</option>
```

Referência: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 0):

Cara o bom é sempre testar possíveis soluções simples e ler ao máximo a API.
Para que você possa testar futuros plugins bootstrap acesse o site [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/).

Seguindo o conceito básico que trata de um objeto HTML utilize o atributo completo para selecionar o option: `selected="selected"`

veja funcionando no [exemploSelect](http://www.bootply.com/lZKzLT1gDr) que fiz.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelo exemplo. Me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score -1):

O live search diferentemente do SELECT se trata de um INPUT, e ele precisa de receber o que será pesquisado, e isso não deve ser pre inserido. Geralmente os resultados O certo é usar placeholder="Tim Martin" no input, para ter um texto no fundo no input . 
No seu caso aí, ainda que você pre-preencha o campo ele so deve atualizar depois que vocÊ editar ao menos um espaço. O ideal é não ter nada, porque ele não trabalha como um campo de pesquisa morta, é uma pesquisa viva (live) .

Comment: Olá @David. Tente colocar código que suporte a sua resposta, nem que seja apenas de exemplo. Fica mais fácil perceber.